# Restrict nodes and terms per user

Tags: 6, organic-groups, users, taxonomy-terms

First of all, I'm using Drupal 6.

I'm developing a website where I want the users to automatically have their own "group"; this means they are only able to see their own nodes. If another user creates an account, he won't have access to other users' nodes. Also, users can add new terms to some fields (using "Hierarchical Select") and I want it to be restricted to each user too.

I also want a user (lets call it "user A") creates another user and they can have access to the user A's "group"; this means that they can see user A's nodes and terms.

I was looking for the Organic Groups module, but it doesn't seem able to do this. If it is, I don't know how to do that.

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

To create something both so specific and complex, you probably won't be able to find modules that will solve this problem for you 100%. So to be able to do this you will have to develop some of this yourself (or pay some one to do it for you)

You best bet will be to start of with organic groups, rules might also help. The fact that you want users to be able to create other users complicate things, as that is something usually done by admin users. Most likely you will have to create your own custom form to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to have a separate subdomain for each group or try to use Spaces module.

Possible solutions for this:

- Drupal Commons
- Open Atrium
- Organic Groups and Spaces (D6, D7 port in progress)

> ### Spaces 3.x
>
> Spaces is an API module intended to make configuration options generally
>   avaliable only at the sitewide level to be configurable and overridden by
>   individual "spaces" on a Drupal site. It has been described as:
>
> - A way to make one Drupal site act like several sites
> - A way to provide much more configurable, full-feature Organic Groups or user
>     homepages
> - A generalized API for contextual configuration"

*(Spaces 3.x README.TXT)*

[Read more](http://drupal.org/node/899914)